# fading the cell in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, fade

I have a table view in which I have implemented `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` by which, on swiping on a particular cell, delete button appears.
Now I want to fade the cell on which finger is swiped so that when delete button appears the cell behind should get faded. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndex:indexPath];cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: Just have a look at the answer and just paste that in your code @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just paste this in your Code :**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.contentView.alpha != 0.5)
    {
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.5];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.editing == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.contentView.alpha != 0.5)
        {
            [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.5];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
        }
    }
       return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.editing == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [self.arrayForRows removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the following method in your class

```
    - (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

       /*
            your code for style of cell being edited
       */

      }
```